# Centering divs and images, margin:0px auto 0px auto not working?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a table where one of the columns has a small 30px image in it, however, I am having a hard time figuring out how to center images/divs that are in other divs, tables, etc...

I am familiar with setting the margin to: "margin:0px auto 0px auto;" however this doesn't always work, and does not work in the example below. I was wondering if someone know of a way to center elements that works more consistantly? Or maybe if there is an explanation as to why my method does not work? The image is only 30px and the td element is 100px or even larger.

```
 <td><a href="#"><img src="images/globe.png" style="width:30px;"></a></td>
```

Comment: On a more general note, padding and margin don't usually work as intended when dealing with inline elements, of which anchors and images both are

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried? `text-align: center;`

http://jsfiddle.net/Eqed4/

Comment: (@MHZ: add that to the `td` elements)

Comment: Yeah, within the style attribute. Though, as Fluidbyte mentions below, a class on the <td> might be a better practice.

Answer (score 0):

For table you can use

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" width="100" height="100">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" >
        <a href="#">
           <img src="{IMG_SRC}" style="width:30px;">
        </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Here in this case, `align="center"` will work for the td tag.

For Div tag,

```
<Div style="width:100px;border:1px solid;line-height: 100px;text-align:center;">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="{IMG_SRC}" style="vertical-align: middle;width:30px;" >
    </a>
</div>
```

Here you have to add  `line-height: 100px;text-align:center;` style for the div element where line height will be height of your div element. Also you have to add `vertical-align: middle;` to your img tag.

This should work.

Please refer working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/QtKHx/)

**Note:** I have added some extra styling like border etc can be removed. Also this solution will make image center vertically and horizontally also.